# Admob native ads: Invalid NativeAdManager type. Found: qa; Required: NativeAdManager

Tags: android, admob

I am posting this question hoping someone maybe found a workaround for this bug.

It is happening with the new Native Express Ads from Admob but the following crash is happening quite frequently (maybe 1% of the users):

```
Invalid NativeAdManager type. Found: qa; Required: NativeAdManager.
```

The bug has been raised in this Google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/xcRD_bEL9YA

The Admob team is aware of this bug since more than 3 weeks but no correction is coming...

**UPDATE:** Since a few days, this similar error also appeared:

```
Invalid NativeAdManager type. Found: com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o; Required: NativeAdManager.
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad It seems only Admob can fix their bug, but they don't seem to consider this bug a priority...